# Windows XP in Hyper V - missing internet and network connectivity with ethernet LAN

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, hyper-v

So after installing Windows 10 Pro with Hyper-V I successfully create a new virtual machine pointing to my old Windows XP Mode hard disk.

Windows XP boots but now asks to be registered/unlocked. However, I can not since it can not connect to internet. (I have original CD + license key)

I have setup a Virtual Switch Manager - external - connected to my physical ethernet network card.

In my hardware settings for the Windows XP virtual machine, I have added a network adapter which I have connec to the above mentioned switch.

But the virtual windows xp still states it can not register/unlock online as it does not have internet connectivity - how can I solve it?

Comment: Could you please clarify if you can log in normally to your XP system, i.e. if you can use it normally but it reminds you of registering / unlocking, or if you already have reached the state where it won't let you do *anything* but the registration, i.e. where the "registration screen" is the "shell" shown directly after logon and you can't start any other program?

Comment: It is the latter. This was an old Windows XP mode disk I had which I guess I never got registered when I created it a *long* time ago

Comment: I don't remember having to activate XP mode back in the day. I would suspect the need for re-activation might be due to the hardware changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never used Hyper-V, but am nevertheless trying to help.

To be sure we are talking about the same thing: You fire up Windows XP in Hyper-V and then, immediately after logon, you get a screen which tells you that Windows must be activated, and your virtualized system (apparently) does not let you do anything else.

In that "registration screen", there should be three options, among them an option like that (I can't remember the exact wording): "Telephone service to activate Windows" or perhaps "Activate Windows by phone" or such. If you can see this option, then why not try it? I have done that several times for customers, and in every case, the service representatives were very friendly and just asked if we did use that Windows copy on other PCs (of course, we didn't). Then they passed our call to some automated system which told us some activation code - problem solved. If you mistrust them, you could suppress your caller ID for that call ...

If you can't or don't want to activate by phone for some reason, you have to deploy a more advanced technique. The easiest way is tricking Windows into opening a file manager window. To do that:

1) In the "registration screen", there should be some help link.

2) Now, hoping that Internet Explorer is your standard browser, if you click on that help link, Internet Explorer will open (please tell us if Internet Explorer isn't your standard browser - I don't want to make it too complicated here).

3) When Internet Explorer has opened, clear its address bar (i.e. clear the current URL).

4) Then, in the blank address bar, type "C:\". Now a *normal Windows File Explorer window* should open. In other words: Using *Internet Explorer*, you just have opened *Windows File Explorer*.

Please note that this is not my invention. I have read about it several times a long time ago.

5) Connect a USB stick to your PC which contains the drivers for the network card which Hyper-V simulates, i.e. the drivers for the virtual network card Windows XP is seeing from within its VM, and make sure that the VM / Windows XP is seeing that USB stick (you may have to change your VM configuration for that, bus as as said above, I don't know anything about Hyper-V).

6) Using your precious File Explorer Window from step 4), install those drivers from the USB stick.

7) If you have a standard configuration (i.e. DHCP server somewhere), then chances are that the Internet works now. In that case, you can now do the activation via Internet. Otherwise, after having installed the drivers, you will have to do the network configuration first.

If you have a problem with one of the steps above, then describe the problem as precise as possible, including screenshots if possible, but at least telling us the literal error messages (if applicable).

Answer (score 1):

A remark : If you have an already-activated VM in the format of
VMware or VirtualBox, its disk-file will work equally well as the system disk
in a new Hyper-V VM.

Sometimes Hyper-V has problem with Internet connectivity under some operating systems.
I have not analyzed the cause of the problem, as the work-around is very simple,
but perhaps it is the lack of a matching network driver.
The work-around is to connect instead the VM to the physical card,
under the limitation that an XP driver is available for it.
However, I note that I never needed to install an additional network driver
for XP, kudos perhaps to its excellently-written generic network driver.

Comment: http://www.zdnet.com/article/windows-xp-end-of-support-in-april-three-more-questions-answered/ XP's activation servers *haven't* been taken down, and I recently did an install and activation of a spare copy I had lying around. And suggesting activation cracks - well, that sort of thing just isn't done.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: These servers haven't worked for me when I tried about 6 months ago. Maybe they have been restored after quite pressure by large Microsoft clients, so their continuing presence is not assured. Not every Windows hack is really illegal, if license conditions permit using XP under this environment, but I took that part off.